# Can I import my FFXIII saves from XBox to PC?

Tags: steam, xbox-360, final-fantasy-13

Is there any way I can import the FFXIII saves from XBox to my computer for Steam?

Comment: Probably not, my understanding is that the Xbox 360 encrypts its saves.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the Xbox saving system, but I once read about exporting Skyrim stuff between 360 and PC.

Here's the reddit thread:
http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/mfgrp/psa_you_can_transfer_skyrim_savegame_files_from/

A search about FFXIII save files yields this:
http://www.reddit.com/r/FinalFantasy/comments/2jew4y/where_are_ffxiii_pc_save_files/
and this:
(see comment for link, not enough rep)

So I'm positive you should only have to retrieve the "ff13-00.dat" file from the Xbox using that "Modio" program and place it in
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\SquareEnix\FinalFantasyXIII\save

For Modio usage, (taken from the first link):
Copy the x360 save file from your Xbox to your 360 Formatted USB Drive. Open with Modio. Click open from device locate the save file and open it. Click the file contents tab. Extract ff13-00.dat.

Comment: Second link:
http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/final-fantasy-xiii-save-editor-tutorial.474501/

Comment: Don't just link elsewhere.  Please answer the question fully.  Links can contain supplemental information, but they themselves do not answer the question.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference. Links that change or die can make an answer that doesn't include the essentials directly worthless in the future.

Comment: I see. Added a bit of instructions about Modio. Problem is, most of the answer stand as it is, given that I don't have the knowledge on Modio or the 360 save system to write even a brief tutorial.

Comment: Sounds like you have some research to do, then.